# Android : How change focus on form with out user action?

Tags: android, forms, android-edittext

I've a form with 2 fields, 
after First login, i store the Mail in SharedPreferences and i restore when user start app again,
But how to set focus on Pass Field ? it's not very nice to see that mail is fill but focus is still on mail field.

Thanks

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/Email" 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/labelEmail" 
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:padding="10px">
</EditText>

<EditText 
android:id="@+id/Pass"  
android:text=""
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/labelPass" 
android:padding="10px"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:password="true">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call `requestFocus()` on the password field.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()

Comment: @anticafe: Did you read the API documentation in the answer's hyperlink?  It does do something, and it is supported in the latest versions of the Android API.  If it's not working for you, I suggest you post a new SO question.